# Activity always on top [Check out bar]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an shopping app and when a customer adds an Item to the shopping cart a bar should appear in the bottom part of the screen, providing the customer to checkout or edit the cart.

This bar should stay in the bottom of the screen until the customer reset the cart or checkout, and it may display recommendations of similar items as those being displayed on the current screen.

How can I make an activity that is always on top, but only cover a set are of the screen?
Maybe I should use fragments, but I'm unsure of having a whole app in a frame just to get this one feature working.

Example: The black bar should stay on top of all activities at all times until checked out.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: " activity that is **always on top**, but only cover a set are of the screen?"  ?? and a bar should **appear** in the bottom part of the screen??  I don't quite understand. Perhaps a visual example and the code you have tried.

Comment: Picture added for clarification*

Comment: You want " a bar should appear in the bottom part of the screen". So you want to change its `Visibility` or its function?? "until the customer reset the cart or checkout"

Comment: If i have a bar thats invisible i must have it in every layout for every activity, right?
I must also pass the data between activities (in this case the item in the cart etc). 
I must also pass data telling the new activity whether or not the bar should be visible.

Maybe in totally lost, but cant you have an activity that runs separate from another at the same time?

How would you solve this problem, in broad strokes?

Comment: You could create a XML fragment layout and add it to each Activity layout you need. Set its `Visibilty` property to `GONE` initially and make it `VISIBLE` when you need to see it.

Comment: That black bottombar is known as `SnackBar`. For this create a `Activity` and place a `Snackbar(with indefinite showing time)` on it. And for `Transition` use `Fragments`, so because of snackbar is  on activity it will visible even if you navigate between your fragments. And you can also easily hide snackbar when you want.

Comment: I see.
So I cant escape turning each activity into a frame.
To bad. There is like 20 activities in there.

Comment: The advantage of having a fragment is that a fragment can have its own functionality. So you do not need to copy code to each `Activity`. Just add the fragment in your `Layout` or do it programmatically in your `Activity` --- Take a look at this::  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Just to clarify. I must/should have one activity for the whole app and convert all other activities into fragment which I can then add to my main (and only) activity?

Comment: No. Create the  activities as you need them. Create a fragment for your "CheckOut" bar and reuse it where you need it.